# Showing Parity of the Associated Legendre Function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, parity

We define the Associated Legendre Function as follows:
$$ P_{\ell}^m (x) = (-1)^m (1-x^2)^{\frac{m}{2}} \left( \frac{d}{dx}\right)^m P_{\ell}(x)$$

How would we show that $P_{\ell}^m (-x) = (-1)^{\ell + m}P_{\ell}^m (x) $? I know it has to do with the chain rule, but I'm very stuck

Note: $P_{\ell}(x)$ is defined as:
$$ P_{\ell} (x) = \frac{1}{2^{\ell} \ell!} \left( \frac{d}{dx} \right)^{\ell} (x^2-1)^{\ell}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go though as follow :

First We will prove $P_l(-x)=(-1)^lP_l(x)$. This can be done as follows
$$P_l(x)=\frac{1}{2^l l!}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^l(x^2-1)^l$$
Going from $x\rightarrow -x$, We have
$$P_l(-x)=\frac{1}{2^l l!}\left(\frac{d}{d(-x)}\right)^l(x^2-1)^l$$
$$P_l(-x)=(-1)^l\frac{1}{2^l l!}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^l(x^2-1)^l$$
$$P_l(-x)=(-1)^lP_l(x)$$

---

$$P_l^m(-x)=(-1)^m(1-x^2)^{m/2}\left(\frac{d}{d(-x)}\right)^mP_l(-x)$$
$$P_l^m(-x)=(-1)^m(1-x^2)^{m/2}(-1)^m\left(\frac{d}{d(-x)}\right)^m(-1)^lP_l(x)$$
$$P_l^m(-x)=(-1)^m(-1)^l(-1)^m(1-x^2)^{m/2}\left(\frac{d}{d(-x)}\right)^mP_l(x)$$
$$P_l^m(-x)=(-1)^{m+l}P_l^m(x)$$
QED :)